# Confounding Coin Chuck Chances

Tags: probability, probability-theory, problem-solving, puzzle

> If a coin is thrown some number of times, coming up heads the last three times, what is the probability that the next (nth) throw will be heads. What is the probability that the (n+9)th throw will be the first time that four heads are thrown in a row?

I came across this recently (I've reworded it), and ended up with the answers 1/2 for part 1 and 1/32 for part b. What do you think? My main concern is that bayesion probability methods can be applied to this, but I really can't see how.

Comment: Part $a$ looks good (assuming it's a fair coin), but part $b$ is hard to follow.  I assume we're not meant to look at all the tosses that went before?  Why start the numbering at $n$?  Do we count the three $H's$?  That is, if the $n^{th}$ toss is $H$, is that four in a row?

Comment: @lulu Yes, If the nth toss is H, that is four in a row. Starting the numbering at n is (I think) arbitrary.

Comment: Ok.  I just posted an answer, assuming that was the case.  Check to see if it does what you had in mind.  My answer is a lot smaller than your $\frac 1{32}$ so it is possible that I am answering a different question.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I follow the meaning of step $b$.  As I understand it, we are looking at the sequence $$HHHa_na_{n+1}a_{n+2}\cdots a_{n+9}$$  and we want the probability that $a_{n+6}a_{n+7}a_{n+8}a_{n+9}$ is the first block of the form $HHHH$ to arise.  To achieve that we need a number of things:

$1.$  we need $a_{n+6},a_{n+7},a_{n+8},a_{n+9}$ to all be $H$...probability $\frac 1{16}$.

$2.$  we need $a_{n+5}$ to be $T$ (were it $H$ then $a_{n+5}a_{n+6}a_{n+7}a_{n+8}$ would be an earlier string of four $H's$...probability $\frac 12$.

$3.$  we need $a_n$ to be $T$ (else the string begins with four $H's$)...probability $\frac 12$.

$4.$  we need $a_{n+1}a_{n+2}a_{n+3}a_{n+4}$ to be anything other than $HHHH$...probability $1-\frac 1{16}=\frac {15}{16}$.

As these are independent events we get the answer by multiplying.  Hence $$\boxed {\frac 1{16}\times \frac 12 \times \frac 12 \times \frac {15}{16}=\frac {15}{1024}}$$

Note: this is about $.015$ which is roughly half of your proposed $\frac 1{32}$.

Comment: Thanks, this does seem to answer the question. I missed out your steps 3 and 4.